# Why is it necessary to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener when setting up a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

**I followed the official documentation:** https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating. It provides the steps to set up a fragment.

1. First, create the fragment class (`extends Fragment')
2. Then create its layout (and, in fragment class' `OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)`, return one of the `View' of this layout using`inflate`)
3. Choose an activity that will use this fragment. This activity must `extends FragmentActivity` and in order to use the fragment, it will contain calls to `FragmentManager`'s methods, `FragmentTransaction`'smethods, etc.

**However, doing this results in a "fatal exception":**

> java.lang.lang.lang.RuntimeException: com.example...TheActivity@efebfcf must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

## Questions

1. Why doesn't the documentation mention this problem?
2. In `TheActivity` (which uses the fragment `TheFragment`), I implemented `TheFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener` (yes, `TheFragment.OnFr...`!). It's weird, isn't it? In addition, this listener provides this method: `onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)` but what is it supposed to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure in the Fragment's `onAttach` method, it will say that the parent activity must implement the `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. This is to facilitate Fragment to Activity communication.

This is not required and the check in `onAttach` can be removed. In fact if you are not doing anything in the `onAttach` method then the whole method can be removed from the `Fragment`