# OnFragmentInteractionListener necessary to implement - where and how is it reported

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[I have found this post for this problem already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343383/why-is-it-necessary-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener-when-setting-up-a), and the problem covers my situation, but this question is different.

I will describe it in short: *it is necessary to implement the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in order for an activity to use a class that extends `Fragment` for e.g. while settings the pages in a ViewPager attached with the `activity` using `fragments` for pages else the following exception occurs:  *

> java.lang.lang.lang.RuntimeException: com.example...TheActivity@efebfcf must implement

[The link to the post says hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343383/why-is-it-necessary-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener-when-setting-up-a) that this check is done somewhere in the `fragment`'s `onAttach` method. But, checking the source code for the `onAttach` in the `Fragment` class:

```
@CallSuper
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        mCalled = true;
        final Activity hostActivity = mHost == null ? null : mHost.getActivity();
        if (hostActivity != null) {
            mCalled = false;
            onAttach(hostActivity);
        }
    }
```

I got this from android studio `ctrl+right_click`ing the `Fragment` class. I don't see where the check is done for if the `activity` implements the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` method. Where is this check done and how does the compiler throw this exception or even know that we've implemented this method(to possibly override it with another listener)?

UPDATE: following are more information on the issue:

**The logcat error: **

```
E/memtrack(16281): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug(16281): failed to load memtrack module: -2
E/memtrack(16294): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug(16294): failed to load memtrack module: -2
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
E/dalvikvm(16305): Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* RESUMING LOGOANIMATION ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* RESUMING LOGOANIMATION ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* RESUMING LOGOANIMATION ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* DESTROYING STARTUPMANAGER ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* DESTROYING STARTUPMANAGER ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* DESTROYING STARTUPMANAGER ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* PAUSING LOGOANIMATION ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* PAUSING LOGOANIMATION ACTIVITY ********************
E/DEBUG:  (16305): ******************* PAUSING LOGOANIMATION ACTIVITY ********************
E/AndroidRuntime(16305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16305): Process: com.nailit.www, PID: 16305
E/AndroidRuntime(16305): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.nailit.www.StartupSetup.StartupPreference@41f23c90 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at com.nailit.www.StartupSetup.Frag_StartPref_Theme.onAttach(Frag_StartPref_Theme.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2574)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:828)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:235)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1927)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5652)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(16305):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
E/android.os.Debug(  615): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 16305 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

**The Fragment code:  **

```
package com.nailit.www.StartupSetup;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.nailit.www.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Frag_StartPref_Layout extends Fragment {


    public Frag_StartPref_Layout() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_startpref_layout, container, false);
    }



}
```

**And the activity that uses the Fragment:  **

```
package com.nailit.www.StartupSetup;
import com.nailit.www.R;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class StartupPreference extends AppCompatActivity{
    private final static int no_of_prefs = 2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup_preference);
        //we're not using the layout natively, but using Fragment's layout
        //but setContentView is required since it is accessed by : R.id.startPref_pager


        StartPrefPagerAdapter prefPagerAdapter =
                new StartPrefPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager StartPref_Viewpager = findViewById(R.id.startPref_pager);

        StartPref_Viewpager.setAdapter(prefPagerAdapter);
    }


    private class StartPrefPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public StartPrefPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return StartupPreference.no_of_prefs;//no. of preference pages
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new Frag_StartPref_Layout();
                case 1:
                    return new Frag_StartPref_Theme();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

**The layout of the activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/startPref_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The layout of the fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/startPref_Layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startPref_layout_info"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startPref_layout_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Frag_startPref_layout_info"

        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startPref_layout_select"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".125"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/startPref_layout_select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dot_animation_holder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".125"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Frag_startPref_Radio1"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Frag_startPref_Radio2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dot_animation_holder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".08"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="dots animation here" />

    </LinearLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's not in `Fragment`'s `onAttach()`. It would be in your `Fragment` subclass's `onAttach()` override.

Comment: @MikeM. , the exception is given by the compiler even when I haven't overriden anything, and not implemented anything

Comment: You may not have overridden that method yourself, but it's somewhere in your project. `OnFragmentInteractionListener` is not an SDK `interface`. It's likely from an Android Studio template (though I thought that hadn't been used in quite a while), and/or from some project you've imported that uses it.

Comment: @MikeM. , how can I see what code has been used for it then? I mean I'd like to see how does it throw that exception

Comment: The specific class should be mentioned in the stack trace that follows that `RuntimeException` line.

Comment: Yes, that's the `StartupPreference` class which I have extended from `Fragment`, but the Fragment's `onAttach` code is shown above and It doesn't contain that check for throwing exception. and I hadn't overriden it myself.

Comment: I can't really suggest anything further without seeing what you're looking at; i.e., the complete stack trace, and the specific `Fragment` class.

Comment: @MikeM. , I have updated my code. could you please take a look?

Comment: The Exception is being thrown in `Frag_StartPref_Theme`'s `onAttach()`.

Comment: @MikeM. , I didn't notice that. I accidentally loaded all the `Fragment`'s factory methods while creating the fragment. and it checks for the interface. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above pointed out by @MikeM , the exception is due to loading the `Factory methods` which is checked by default while creating a fragment. The code included checks for the interface.